# Changes to how the forge request component works (in v2)

Tags: trigger.io

We've been running Forge v2 for just over a month now. We switched over on a delayed basis because our forge web app (on node) is heavily customized and migrating is a manual process.

A week ago I noticed that non 200OK HTTP statuses from our API were not being handled properly by our app. The problem seemed to be that the responseText property of the error object was missing. This is a pretty important property as we return error information as JSON when the request is non 200OK.

The v2 documentation refers to a `content` property and not `responseText` but both properties are missing - https://trigger.io/modules/request/current/docs/index.html

I can confirm that this functionality worked before because when I reverted the all.js file to a date before the v2 upgrade, it started working again. After some rooting about with the source, the problem seems to be with this method in the `all.js` file.

```
    e.ajax({
        url: "/_forge/proxy/" + p.match(/\/\/([^\/:]+)/)[1].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\./g, "/") + "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: t,
        dataType: "text",
        timeout: w,
        success: A &&
        function(E) {
            try {
                if (x == "xml") {
                    var D, C;
                    if (window.DOMParser) {
                        D = new DOMParser();
                        C = D.parseFromString(E, "text/xml")
                    } else {
                        C = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                        C.async = "false";
                        C.loadXML(E)
                    }
                    E = C
                } else {
                    if (x == "json") {
                        E = JSON.parse(E)
                    }
                }
            } catch(F) {}
            A(E)
        },
        error: function(E, C, D) { //E variable has the responseText property, but is not passed along in the callback function
            v({
                message: "api.ajax with " + JSON.stringify(B) + "failed. " + C + ": " + D,
                type: "EXPECTED_FAILURE",
                status: C,
                statusCode: E.status,
                err: D
            })
        }
    })
```

After unminifying the all.js file, it's around the 6800 line mark where you declare the request.ajax object.

Steps to reproduce

1. Make API call using forge.request with an error callback
2. Have a PHP file return JSON with a non 200OK status
3. Inside error callback, there is no responseText property to access the API response text

My Trigger control panel doesn't show that I need an update, and all modules are up to date as far as I know.

Is this a regression in forge functionality or is this intended functionality?

Comment: We've not heard of a general problem retrieving JSON data via forge.request on the web target. Could you comment with the endpoint url you are calling, or send to support@tigger.io so we can test against that?

Comment: It only happens when you get a non 200 response. Everything else is fine. Will try to open up the url and add it here.